# limit client ip address connections, nginx

Tags: python, nginx, flask, virtual-machine, gunicorn

i'm in the middle of learning the basics of deployment of a simple weather web app using VM, flask, Nginx and gunicorn.
i've been told to limit the amount of connections from the same ip address to 5. meaning - i would like that each ip client could open only 5 connections to my site.
according to this link:
[Manual for limiting number of connections](https://www.tecmint.com/limit-connections-in-nginx/)

i'm supposed to add this line in the http part:

```
limit_conn_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=limitconnbyaddr:20m;
```

then add this line to my location block:

```
limit_conn   limitconnbyaddr  5;
```

and afterwards, of course, test nginx, restart the service and check myself.
my question is: how can i check myself?
i can't figure out a way to test if my actions were good or not.
(BTW, if i'm wrong - i'd like to have a good explanation to the correct way to solve it, if anyone can)
the website is made using python (as flask mentioned above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick tool to test rate limit scenarios is `siege`. Assuming you're using Debian-base distributions, install it using:

```bash
sudo apt-get install siege
```

Usage:

```bash
# -v - verbose logging
# -r 2 - run two tests
# -c 5 - open 5 concurrent connections
siege -v -r 2 -c 5 http://localhost:8080/static/img/logo.png
```

Sample output (the failed requests will appear in red):

```bash
** SIEGE 4.0.7
** Preparing 5 concurrent users for battle.
The server is now under siege...
HTTP/1.1 200     0.84 secs:   84987 bytes ==> GET  /static/img/logo.png
HTTP/1.1 200     0.96 secs:   84987 bytes ==> GET  /static/img/logo.png
HTTP/1.1 200     1.02 secs:   84987 bytes ==> GET  /static/img/logo.png
HTTP/1.1 200     1.02 secs:   84987 bytes ==> GET  /static/img/logo.png
HTTP/1.1 200     1.02 secs:   84987 bytes ==> GET  /static/img/logo.png
HTTP/1.1 200     0.92 secs:   84987 bytes ==> GET  /static/img/logo.png
HTTP/1.1 200     0.93 secs:   84987 bytes ==> GET  /static/img/logo.png
HTTP/1.1 200     0.90 secs:   84987 bytes ==> GET  /static/img/logo.png
HTTP/1.1 200     0.96 secs:   84987 bytes ==> GET  /static/img/logo.png
HTTP/1.1 200     0.97 secs:   84987 bytes ==> GET  /static/img/logo.png

Transactions:                 10 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:               1.99 secs
Data transferred:           0.81 MB
Response time:              0.95 secs
Transaction rate:           5.03 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.41 MB/sec
Concurrency:                4.79
Successful transactions:          10
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            1.02
Shortest transaction:           0.84
```

Sidenote: if the verbose format (`-v`) still shows you a JSON output, edit the siege configuration file (located at `~/.siege/siege.conf`) and set the `json_output` directive to `false`; this should solve the issue.

Comment: thank you for your answer. just for the sake of my understanding - if i limit my connections from the same ip address to 5, and run the test with siege when -c is 10 - but every output is blue (assuming it's the ok color) - the answer to my test should be noted on the concurrency right?

Comment: I guess you're not setting the `rate` parameter properly; check out the first code snippet from [nginx rate-limiting blog post](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/). It worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi @Pedram, thank you for your kind answers. i've been testing this for the last few days, i can see that the concurrent connections can still be OVER the limit i've adjusted, is it possible? i think it shouldn't be possible, but maybe i'm wrong